# Express.js Routing - Restrict a parameterized URL within two options

Tags: node.js, express

I have a couple of URL endpoints that look like following

```
/api/comments/approve?ids=<comment-ids>
```

And

```
/api/comments/reject?ids=<comment-ids>
```

I have a handler/controller function that will handle requests to both endpoints, performing appropriate operation identified by approve/reject part of the URL.

What I'd like to have in my routes configuration, is a URL configuration that will allow me to parameterize the URL, and at the same time restrict the parameter between 'approve' and 'reject', so that the handler is invoked only when request is made to the one of the above endpoints.

```
/api/comments/:action[approve|reject]?ids=<comment-ids>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex to capture the route.

```
app.get(/^\/api\/comments\/(approve|reject)/, function(req, res, next) {
    var action = req.params[0]; //will contain either approve or reject, anything else will return a 404.
    var ids = req.query.ids;
    if(!ids) return next(new Error('No ids present'));
});
```

Or you could do it how you are now, but use `app.param` to control the parameter.

```
app.param('action', function (req, res, next, action) {
    if(action !== 'approve' && action !== 'reject') {
        return next(new Error('Action is neither approve or reject.'));
    }
    next();
});

app.get('/api/comments/:action', function() {
    var action = req.params.action;
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to parameterize the last portion of the url, so it can be access through req.param? For example, if the parameter is named 'action', I could do var action = req.param.get('action').

Comment: @rubayeet I've added another way to do it, which is more controlled and may be better suited to you.